# java nested class inner and outer reference equals

Tags: java

```
public class Outer2 {

 Outer2(){
    System.out.println("Calling Outer2 constructor");
    System.out.println(this.getClass().getName() + ": Inner class reference is " + this);
    System.out.println(Outer2.this + ": Outer class reference is " + Outer2.this);
 }

 class Inner1 extends Outer2 {
    Inner1() {
        System.out.println("Calling Inner1 constructor");
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getName() + ": Inner class reference is " + this);
        System.out.println(Outer2.this + ": Outer class reference is " + Outer2.this);
    }
}

 class Inner2 extends Inner1 {
    Inner2() {
        System.out.println("Calling Inner2 constructor");
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getName() + ": Inner class reference is " + this);
        System.out.println(Outer2.this + ": Outer class reference is " + Outer2.this);
    }
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Outer2().new Inner2();
}
```

}

Can someone explain why the above code gives the following output:

```
 Calling Outer2 constructor
 outer2.Outer2: Inner class reference is outer2.Outer2@15db9742
 outer2.Outer2@15db9742: Outer class reference is outer2.Outer2@15db9742
 Calling Outer2 constructor
 outer2.Outer2$Inner2: Inner class reference is 
 outer2.Outer2$Inner2@6d06d69c
 outer2.Outer2$Inner2@6d06d69c: Outer class reference is 
 outer2.Outer2$Inner2@6d06d69c
 Calling Inner1 constructor
 outer2.Outer2$Inner2: Inner class reference is 
 outer2.Outer2$Inner2@6d06d69c
 outer2.Outer2@15db9742: Outer class reference is outer2.Outer2@15db9742
 Calling Inner2 constructor
 outer2.Outer2$Inner2: Inner class reference is 
 outer2.Outer2$Inner2@6d06d69c
 outer2.Outer2@15db9742: Outer class reference is outer2.Outer2@15db9742
```

I'm interested in why the inner and outer class reference equals when calling Outer2 supertype constructor second time?

Comment: What else should it be? You have only two objects created.

Comment: The outer class reference is outer2.Outer2@15db9742, that's clear. But when the Outer2 constructor called second time the Outer reference is different. That's what I don't get. When calling Inner1 constructor and Inner2 constructor the inner and outer reference make sense for me. Why the inner and outer reference is swapped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Outer2 constructor, you're not in any inner class of Outer2. So, for the compiler, the line

```
System.out.println(Outer2.this + ": Outer class reference is " + Outer2.this);
```

is strictly equivalent to

```
System.out.println(Outer2.this + ": Outer class reference is " + this);
```

So the value of `this` , is printed twice. And since `this` is actually a reference to the Inner2 object being created, it prints `outer2.Outer2$Inner2@6d06d69c`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That makes sense.